# Issues With login/regstration

Tags: android, android-activity

*UPDATED*still haveing issues please if you see any errors please let me know, i would like to put my logcat in but i cant access it due to the errors .......I'm having issues with my login and registration mechanism. I'm probably doing something wrong, but when i try to test out the login my app crashes with the message "...has suddenly stopped." msg. Also, my textview that goes to my registration class isnt responding. Can some please help me?

I know there is probably a lot of errors, but be kind I'm new to this :)
If anyone is generous or just bored and wanted to personally help me out with issues please leave your email

Below is the code for my login class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setting default screen to login.xml

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUp.class);
            startActivity(i);




    // create a instance of SQLite Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Get The Reference Of Buttons
    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


    }
// Methods to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
public void signIn(View V) {
    try{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LoginScreen.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");

    // get the References of views
    final EditText loginUsername = (EditText) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.liUsername);
    final EditText loginPassword = (EditText) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.liPassword);

    Button btnSignIn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
    // Set On ClickListener
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get The User name and Password

            String username = loginUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

            // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
            String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter
                    .getSingleEntry(username);

            // check if the Stored password matches with Password entered by
            // user
            if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,
                        "Congrats: Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                dialog.dismiss();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,
                        "User Name or Password does not match",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dialog.show();
            }       
}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    super.startActivity(intent);
    Intent mainpage = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainPage.class);
    startActivity(mainpage);
    finish();
    }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }


    }


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try{
        super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("onDestroy - Error", e.getMessage());
    }
```

MY registration class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set View to register.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
    // Listening to Login Screen link
    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // Closing registration screen
            // Switching to Login Screen/closing register screen
            finish();

    // get Instance of Database Adapter
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Get References of Views
    reg_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);
    reg_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
    reg_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    reg_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    reg_confirmpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_confirmpassword);

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String fullname = reg_fullname.getText().toString();
            String username = reg_username.getText().toString();
            String password = reg_password.getText().toString();
            String email = reg_email.getText().toString();
            String confirmPassword = reg_confirmpassword.getText()
                    .toString();

            // check if any of the fields are vacant
            if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")
                    || confirmPassword.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // check if both password matches
            if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            } else {
                // Save the Data in Database
                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(username, password);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        super.onDestroy();
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("onDestroy - Error", e.getMessage());
    }}
```

Comment: You should post your errors that can be found in Logcat.

Comment: Check : http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know your code errors it's, put all your code in a block try-catch in all functions..

```
try{
   //your code here
}catch(Exception e){
   Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}
```

in Logcat will be apears in red color the errors of your code, "tag" it's a way to differentiate the erros like:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try{
       super.onDestroy();
       loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("onDestroy - Error", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: thanks a bit im still struggling im start to put the try and catch methods in but just more errors im thinking its just maybe "}" here and theres just more errors sorry for the inconvinces