# Login Screen issues and data verification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

*updated version*  my issues right now are the fact my login button doesn't do anything when i press it and also i want to be able for my login screen to verify if an account was created during my registration activity and access its info and processed to my main class

my login screen

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {
private Button btnLogin;
private TextView registerScreen;

private LoginDataBaseAdapter dataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setting default screen to login.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    registerScreen = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    // create a instance of SQLite Database
    dataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    dataBaseAdapter.open();

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LoginScreen.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");

    // get the References of views
    final EditText loginUsername = (EditText) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.liUsername);
    final EditText loginPassword = (EditText) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.liPassword);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = loginUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();
            login(username, password);

        }

        private void login(String username, String password) {
            // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
            String storedPassword = dataBaseAdapter
                    .getSingleEntry(username);

            // check if the Stored password matches with Password entered by
            // user
            if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,
                        "Congrats: Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                dialog.dismiss();

                Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainPage.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,
                        "User Name or Password does not match",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // This called whenever btnlogin is clicked:
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this, SignUp.class));

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try {
        super.onDestroy();
        dataBaseAdapter.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("onDestroy - Error", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

and my registration class incase you would like to see it

```
public  class SignUp extends Activity {
    private EditText reg_fullname, reg_username, reg_email, reg_password ;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private LoginDataBaseAdapter dataBaseAdapter;
    private TextView loginScreen;
    protected DataBaseHelper DB = new DataBaseHelper(SignUp.this); 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set View to register.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

         reg_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);
         reg_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
         reg_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
         reg_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);

        loginScreen = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
        //Listening to Login Screen Link
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        // get Instance of Database Adapter
        dataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        dataBaseAdapter.open();

        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {       

                switch(v.getId()){

                    case R.id.link_to_login:
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, LoginScreen.class));
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){  

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (v.getId()){

                    case R.id.btnRegister:
                        // I think they have to be final to be used in the onClickListener
                        final String fullname = reg_fullname.getText().toString();
                        final String username = reg_username.getText().toString();
                        final String password = reg_password.getText().toString();
                        final String email = reg_email.getText().toString();

                        boolean invalid = false;

                       if(fullname.equals(""))
                       {
                            invalid = true;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                       else

                            if(username.equals(""))
                            {
                                invalid = true;
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        else

                            if(password.equals(""))
                            {
                                invalid = true;
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            else 
                                if(email.equals(""))
                                {
                                    invalid = true;
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    // btnLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.d("FULLNAME", fullname);
                                    Log.d("PASSWORD",password);
                                    Log.d("USERNAME",username);
                                    Log.d("EMAIL",email);
                                    Intent i=new Intent(SignUp.this,MainPage.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    // Save the Data in Database
                                    dataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(fullname, username,password,email);

                              }break;
                        }

                    }


                });

             }      

            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    super.onDestroy();
                    dataBaseAdapter.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                   Log.e("onDestroy SignUp- Error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            private void addEntry(String fullname,  String username, String password, String email) 
            {

                SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("FULLNAME", fullname);
                values.put("USERNAME", username);
                values.put("PASSWORD", password);
                values.put("EMAIL", email);

                try
                {
                    db.insert(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your details submitted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: is login(View v) in your onClick in your XML or how is it being called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues With login/regstration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252645/issues-with-login-regstration)

Comment: Check : http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           new login().execute();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am not understanding what you are doing I would move your click listener to the onCreate and then call login onClick with your values. So move this to the onCreate and then handle the data in a login(String username, String password) method. Untested but move something like this to the onCreate and remove the listener from the Login method

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LoginScreen.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
dialog.setTitle("Login");

// get the References of views
final EditText loginUsername = (EditText) dialog
        .findViewById(R.id.liUsername);
final EditText loginPassword = (EditText) dialog
        .findViewById(R.id.liPassword);

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String username = loginUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

        login(username, password);
    }

});
```

Comment: i added and moved what you recommended but now when i click the login button "unfortunately app has stopped"